# What does the "-" in "bash -" mean?

Tags: command-line, bash

What does `bash -` mean in the following bash shell code? It seems to be used to take the output the last code as the input. If so, can I just write it as `bash` or `xargs bash`?

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When in doubt, read the source code.  =)

[Bash 4.3, `shell.c` line 830, in function `parse_shell_options()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961#n830):

```c
  /* A single `-' signals the end of options.  From the 4.3 BSD sh.
     An option `--' means the same thing; this is the standard
     getopt(3) meaning. */
  if (arg_string[0] == '-' &&
       (arg_string[1] == '\0' ||
         (arg_string[1] == '-' && arg_string[2] == '\0')))
    return (next_arg);
```

In other words, the `-` is saying that there are **no more options**.  If there were any more words on the command line, they would be treated as a filename, even if the word started with a `-`.

In your example, of course, that `-` is completely redundant, as there is nothing following it anyway.  In other words, **`bash -` is exactly equivalent to `bash`**.

---

Bash takes its commands

1. from a script file if it's provided on the command line, or
2. non-interactively from its stdin if its stdin is not a TTY (such as in your example: stdin is a pipe, so Bash will execute the contents of that URL as a script), or
3. interactively if its stdin is a TTY.

It is a misconception that `bash -` tells Bash to read its commands from its standard input.  While it *is* true that in your example, Bash will read its commands from stdin, it would have done so regardless of whether there was a `-` on the command line, because, as stated above, `bash -` is identical to `bash`.

To further illustrate that `-` does not mean stdin, consider:

- The `cat` command is designed to interpret a `-` as stdin.  For example:

  ```
  $ echo xxx | cat /etc/hosts - /etc/shells
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  xxx
  # /etc/shells: valid login shells
  /bin/sh
  /bin/dash
  /bin/bash
  /bin/rbash
  /bin/zsh
  /usr/bin/zsh
  /usr/bin/screen
  /bin/tcsh
  /usr/bin/tcsh
  /usr/bin/tmux
  /bin/ksh93
  ```
- In contrast, you can't get Bash to execute `/bin/date` then `/bin/hostname` by trying this:

  ```
  $ echo date | bash - hostname
  /bin/hostname: /bin/hostname: cannot execute binary file
  ```

  Rather, it tries to interpret `/bin/hostname` as a shell script file, which fails because it's a bunch of binary gobbledygook.
- You can't execute `date +%s` using `bash -` either.

  ```
  $ date +%s
  1448696965
  $ echo date | bash -
  Sat Nov 28 07:49:31 UTC 2015
  $ echo date | bash - +%s
  bash: +%s: No such file or directory
  ```

---

Can you write `xargs bash` instead?  No.  `curl | xargs bash` would invoke bash with the contents of the script as command-line arguments.  The first word of the contents would be the first argument, and it would likely be misinterpreted as a script filename.

Comment: upvote for the only right answer.

Comment: Indeed: in the words of the manpage `An argument of - is equivalent to --.`

Comment: If you really, really wanted to use `xargs` instead, it would work (in the limited scenario of a small enough input script) with `| xargs bash -c`; but really, this is not a useful or idiomatic use of `xargs`.

Comment: @tripleee If the contents of the URL are anything more than a one-liner, then the line breaks and other delimiters would probably be all wrong.

Comment: Duh, you're right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The intention of the command is to pipe the output from the curl command to bash so it immediately executes commands returned by curl.  Basically it tells bash to get its input from stdin.  See https://superuser.com/a/1494190/234355

However, there is some discussion about whether this actually works or not in that same answer.
If you just execute the first part of the command in the question `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup`, it will output a valid bash script.  I didn't try it, not wanting to execute some unknown script from the internet.