# install Oracle Virtual Machine by adding a repository

Tags: apt, virtualbox, oracle

I want to install the Oracle Virtualbox by adding a repository with the `apt-add-repository` command. In order to gain experience in using the apt commands, I would not like to directly modify the sources.list file.
I understand I also need to add the key.
I found in the [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation) the following command to insert :

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list" && wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

---

Unfortunately I do not understand what it does. Can anyone "dismantle" this command and give me the separate list of the commands I should use?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*When you encounter commands that you don't understand, use manual pages.*

This big command can be separated in three main parts :

1. Adding VirtualBox repository to the system
2. Register Oracle public keys
3. Installing Oracle VirtualBox

---

### 1. Adding VirtualBox repository to the system

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list"
```

Let's breack up each part :

`sh -c`

If you type `man sh` you will get :

```
-c               Read commands from the command_string operand
                 instead of from the standard input.  Special
                 parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand  
                 and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)
                 set from the remaining argument operands.
```

---

Now :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free
```

is the address where the VirtualBox packages are located.

When you run the command `lsb_release -cs` it will output your Ubuntu version :

```
$ lsb_release -cs
trusty
```

---

`>` is a redirection operator. It writes the previous output to the following file :

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

When you run

```
echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free'
```

it will output in your terminal :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free
```

Running

```
echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

will write the line :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian '$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free
```

to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` file instead of giving a terminal output.

**Note :** This is not the advised method to use. It may lead to duplicate entries when running twice.

The recommended way to add the VirtualBox repository to the system is `add-apt-repository` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib"
```

*Replace **trusty** with your current Ubuntu version.*

---

### 2. Register Oracle public keys

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
```

`man wget` output :

```
DESCRIPTION
       GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from
       the Web

[...]

-q
       --quiet
           Turn off Wget's output.
```

With this command you download the VirtualBox public key...

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O-
```

...and register it to the system ([What does the “-” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/703397/338915)):

```
sudo apt-key add -
```

---

### 3. Installing Oracle VirtualBox

```
sudo apt-get update
```

`man apt-get` output :

```
   update
       update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
       sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
       location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list.
```

---

And finally `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0` installs the `virtualbox-5.0` package.

---

If you need additional clarification, do not hesitate to ask.

---

More information you can find in the answer from [@takkat](https://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940).
There is a list of all separated commands necessary to install VirtualBox.

Comment: Can you do this with `apt-add-repository`?

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo : sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib" -  Replace wily with the Ubuntu edition you use. :)

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo I missed this part of the question. I have updated my answer ;)

Comment: Thanl you so much for this help. However on my machine the sudo add-apt-repository seems to create a problem in the apt-get update. I needed to add http:// in front of the download.virtualbox.org/......

Comment: @piscvau Glad it helped you.  Yes if you have Ubuntu 14.04 it is the correct command ;)

Comment: Don't I have to setup priorities for the Oracle virtual box over the virtual box which is in the Ubuntu ppa? If so How do I do it?

Comment: No it is done by default. Ubuntu will use the repository with the highest Virtualbox version (so the Oracle one).